# What are defaults for routes namespaces?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

What are the default values for `$app->routes->namespaces` for a [Mojolicious](https://docs.mojolicious.org) application?

I can not find this from documentation:

- https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious#routes
- https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Routes#namespaces

Comment: https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious.pm#L157-L158 ?

Comment: @k-mx: Do you mean that this is not documented?